# getExternalFilesDir returns inconsistent directories

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fileprovider

I have an action that allows users to download images, and I save them to my app's data directory.

I create the temp file like so:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun Context.createPrivateMediaFile(prefix: String, extension: String): File {
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
    val imageFileName = "${prefix}_${timeStamp}_"
    val storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, extension, storageDir)
}
```

and I use it like so:

```
try {
    photoFile = createPrivateMediaFile(".png")
} catch (e: IOException) {
    errorRef = e
} finally {
    if (photoFile == null) {
        callback(null)
    } else {
        tempFilePath = photoFile.absolutePath
        L.d("Temp image path $tempFilePath")
        // File created; proceed with request
        val photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                photoFile)
        photoFile.outputStream().use { resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, it) }
        callback(photoURI)
    }
}
```

The purpose is to create a new file in my data dir, save the file, and then emit the uri through a callback.

This method works most of the time, but I've gotten reports where the uri cannot be resolved. In those cases, the printed error is:

`Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.pitchedapps.frost/files/Fotos/Frost_20170819_111929_1351301627.png`

My file provider contains the folowing path:

```
<external-path
    name="Frost_images"
    path="Android/data/com.pitchedapps.frost/files/Pictures" />
```

so it's weird to me where the `Fotos` folder is coming from. This error has also occurred to me once, so it shouldn't be a locale issue.

So why does `getExternalFilesDir` seem to return varying paths? Is there a way of getting a base data directory that is ensured to stay consistent?

Yet another example is the following path error:

`Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.pitchedapps.frost/cache/Frost_20170819_115054_2013474631.png`.

Attached below are my

[full activity source code](https://github.com/AllanWang/Frost-for-Facebook/blob/dev/app/src/main/kotlin/com/pitchedapps/frost/activities/ImageActivity.kt)

and my

[media utils](https://github.com/AllanWang/KAU/blob/dev/mediapicker/src/main/kotlin/ca/allanwang/kau/mediapicker/MediaUtils.kt)